# PHP: Parse document / text into sentences

Tags: php, parsing

I am looking for a PHP equivalent along the lines of: http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/intl/collation/textBound.html

My goal is to be able to take arbitrary text and split it into sentences (realizing of course that not every (.) ends a sentence.

Does anyone know of a library or method?