# Split variable content into multiple paragraphs

Tags: php

Hey there,
I have this little php code:

```
<p class="category_text"><? echo $category_text; ?></p>
```

I waht to split the $category_text and get something like this:

This is sentence 1 of category_text

This is sentence 2 of category_text

and so on...

$category_text has about 300 words and lets say 6 sentences. How could I split the text in multiple paragraphs (delimited by the stop sings ".")

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo  '<p class="category_text">' 
      . implode('</p><p class="category_text">', explode('.',$string))
      .'</p>';
```

Comment: I think this is the opposite ;)

Comment: Glad I asked this here, my php is to weak:) for this answer:) ty

Answer (score 1):

You can just replace the "." by the tag "
":

```
<p class="category_text"><? echo str_replace('.', '.<br />', $category_text); ?></p>
```

It's not a perfect solution! But if you text is simple enough this little trick should work.

For example if you have a line with 3 dots:

```
$category_text = "Ok...";
```

It will show up like that:

```
OK.
.
.
```

Also if your sentences finish by "?" or "!" you can also use that:

```
<p class="category_text"><? echo str_replace(array('.', '!', '?'), array('.<br />', '!<br />', '?<br />'), $category_text); ?></p>
```

PS: My solution will create one paragraph "

" but with multiple line break

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an array, and then output the lines one by one.  A sentence ending in ... would still be recognized as still ends in ". ".

```
$sentences = explode('. ', $category_text)

foreach($sentences as $val)
{
    echo $val . ".<br /><br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to split a text into sentences, which is not trivial - using `explode(".", $string)` does often not give good results.

Search Stackoverflow for "php split sentence", or directly try the solution to [PHP: Parse document / text into sentences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585630/php-parse-document-text-into-sentences) :

> http://www.zubrag.com/scripts/text-splitter.php

Once you have an array with sentences, use

```
echo '<p>' . implode('</p><p>', $sentences) . '</p>';
```

to echo them out.